# Global object access in strict mode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var global = (function(){
    return this;
}());
```

When this executes global will point to `window` object in browser. 

But this doesn't work in strict mode. Why?

Comment: `return window;` in strict mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason was already explained by dystroy: `this` will not be the global object in strict mode. Here is the workaround (assuming that's running on the global scope):

```
var global = (function(g){
    return g;
}(this));
```

The reason, according to the [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#C), is:

> If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is not coerced to an object. A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object

Comment: How does this differ from `var global = this;`?

Comment: It doesn't. The purpose is to facilitate access to the global object inside the function.

Comment: But you're right to point out that it doesn't make any sense. I think what the OP is looking for is the eval solution suggested by Nathan Wall.

Answer (score 10):

The ES5 specification allows you to retrieve the global object through an indirect eval.

```
var global = (0, eval)('this');
```

This works in both strict and non-strict mode.

An indirect eval is basically a call to eval made by value rather than reference (or without the name of the value binding being "eval"). Indirect eval is executed in global scope, and `this` in global scope refers to the global object.

There is a detailed article covering this at: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: Thank you dude.. that't what i exactly need..

Answer (score 1):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) :

```
for a strict mode function, the specified this is used unchanged:
...
"use strict";
function fun() { return this; }
assert(fun() === undefined);
```

So this is exactly as specified.